# Some problems creating german bibliography using Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am trying to generate a german bibliography using Bibtex. Here are some three examples of my items:

```
@book{Kirchgässner-Wolters-2007,
  AUTHOR        = "Kirchgässner, Gebhard and Wolters, Jürgen",
  EDITOR        = "",
  TITLE         = "Introduction to Modern Time Series Analysis",
  language      = "",
  edition       = "1",
  series        = "",
  address       = "",
  PUBLISHER     = "Springer",
  month         = "",
  YEAR          = "2007",
  volume        = "",
  number        = "",
  note          = "",
  url           = ""
}


@unpublished{Chun-Lin-2010,
  AUTHOR        = "Chun-Lin, Liu",
  TITLE         = "A Tutorial of the Wavelet Transform",
  language      = "",
  month         = "February",
  year          = "2010",
  NOTE          = "unpublished",
  url           = ""
}

 @misc{Hyndman-Athamasopoulos-2012,
   author = "Hyndman, Rob J. and Athanasopoulos, George",
   title = "Forecasting: principles and practice",
   year = "2012",
   url = "https://www.otexts.org/book/fpp",
   note = "[Online; accessed 21-February-2014]"
 }
```

The code I used is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babelbib} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibtemplate} 
\bibliographystyle{babunsrt}


\end{document}
```

This results in the following bibliography:

[image]

I have three problems with this:

(1) I would like to have it without numbers but instead sorted and with indents for the following lines of the same item

(2) What should I do to change the "unpublished" to german version?

(3) I keep getting a warning message `package babelbib error no url command defined but field url used`

I find some solutions for one problem, but the others remain unsolved or it rusuls in new problems.

If I could, I would place a bounty on this, but have to wait for that for two days...

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Why don't you use biblatex and biber instead of bibgerm and babunsrt?

Comment: I have all my bibliography in a bib-file. Can I use biblatex anyway?

Comment: biblatex/biber handle .bib-files as well! It has different ways to sort/split your bibliography, and also language support with predefined strings.

Comment: at 2) do you have a multilingual text, or why don't you translate it manually to "Unveröffentlicht". at 3) you have to include a package, which defines the `\url`-command, like the `url`-package, or the fine `hyperref`-package. 1) biblatex would have an option `dashed` which will do that automatically for you

Comment: @musicman thanks! I will make myself familiar with biblatex...

Comment: @musicman Can you please give me a hint how I can change "unpublished" to "unveröffentlicht"? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be interested in a `biblatex/biber`-solution as well, the following gives you a MWE with your data for a german document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,dashed]{biblatex}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{Kirchgässner-Wolters-2007,
  AUTHOR        = "Kirchgässner, Gebhard and Wolters, Jürgen",
  TITLE         = "Introduction to Modern Time Series Analysis",
  edition       = "1",
  PUBLISHER     = "Springer",
  YEAR          = "2007",
}

@unpublished{Chun-Lin-2010,
  AUTHOR        = "Chun-Lin, Liu",
  TITLE         = "A Tutorial of the Wavelet Transform",
  month         = "February",
  year          = "2010",
  howpublished  = "Unveröffentlicht",
}

@book{Hyndman-Athamasopoulos-abook,
  author = "Hyndman, Rob J. and Athanasopoulos, George",
  title = "Some other book",
  year = "2012",
  url = "https://somewherintheinternet.org",
  urldate = "2014-02-21"
}

@online{Hyndman-Athamasopoulos-2012,
  author = "Hyndman, Rob J. and Athanasopoulos, George",
  title = "Forecasting: principles and practice",
  year = "2012",
  url = "https://www.otexts.org/book/fpp",
  urldate = "2014-02-21"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

blabla\autocite{Chun-Lin-2010}, blabla\autocite[vgl.][4]{Hyndman-Athamasopoulos-abook}, \enquote{ain't no good}\autocite[14]{Hyndman-Athamasopoulos-abook}

\nocite{*}%include the rest in the bibliography, too.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I've also included some packages you maybe interested in. However, be sure to use the right encoding in your editor, which for this document is utf-8 without BOM.

When it comes to point 2), there are different ways. If it's a german document only (not multilingual), you can use the `howpublished`-field, which may be the simplest method (you can also you the `@misc`-entrytype instead of `@unpublished` etc.). If you have more unpublished works, it maybe interesting to modify the bibliography driver for `@unpublished` and include `Unveröffentlicht` manually, so it will be printed for all unpublished works; or the finest solution (for multilingual support): You declare a bibliography-string, and add that in the bibliography driver.

Comment: Note that the `babel` option of `csquotes` is depreciated. Instead use `autostyle`.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer.

Comment: A hopeless thing! First I got 5 Warning messages, then I ran as instructed some of the bib files, then I had 5 errors!

Comment: you have to run pdflatex-biber-pdflatex(-pdflatex). If that doesn't work, post your errors.